# Accuracy matrices for binary classification with sequential() model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have created a deep neural network model with `sequential()` model of keras. This is a binary classification problem. I have fitted the `model` with train data.

I am confused about the calculation of different accuracy metrics for train and validation data. I am calculating RMSE, F1 Score, AUC of ROC and PR curve as,

```
# Prediction
y_pred_train = model.predict(x_train_df).ravel()
y_pred_val = model.predict(x_val_df).ravel()

# RMSE
rmse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train_df, y_pred_train)
rmse_val = mean_squared_error(y_val_df, y_pred_val)

# ROC-AUC
fpr_train, tpr_train, thresholds_roc_train = roc_curve(y_train_df, y_pred_train, pos_label=None)
fpr_val, tpr_val, thresholds_roc_val = roc_curve(y_val_df, y_pred_val, pos_label=None)

roc_auc_train = auc(fpr_train, tpr_train)
roc_auc_val = auc(fpr_val, tpr_val)

# PR-AUC
precision_train, recall_train, thresholds_pr_train = precision_recall_curve(y_train_df, y_pred_train)
precision_val, recall_val, thresholds_pr_val = precision_recall_curve(y_val_df, y_pred_val)
pr_auc_train = auc(recall_train, precision_train)
pr_auc_val = auc(recall_val, precision_val)

# F1 Score
f1_train = np.mean(2 * (precision_train * recall_train) / (precision_train + recall_train))
f1_val = np.mean(2 * (precision_val * recall_val) / (precision_val + recall_val))
```

The values of these accuracies are,

- RMSE Train           **0.11**
- RMSE Validation      **0.13**
- ROC-AUC Train        **0.94**
- ROC-AUC Validation   **0.91**
- PR-AUC Train         **0.96**
- PR-AUC Validation    **0.93**
- F1 Score Train       **0.66**
- F1 Score Validation  **0.66**

I am very new to machine learning. I have implemented these codes by searching various web pages. **Is my code correct?** I am getting this confusion as the F1 score is not very high although all other metrics have high values.

**If the code is correct, then why I'm getting not so high F1 score?**

*Edit 1*

As asked in the comment, the precision and recall values are

```
print(np.mean(precision_train))
print(np.mean(recall_train))
print(np.mean(precision_val))
print(np.mean(recall_val))
```

Output:

```
0.9299899169174257
0.6012312742646909
0.8988925808831595
0.6052356704530617
```

Comment: Why not print the precisions and recalls in order to have an idea of why f1 scores are like that?

Comment: Added these values in question. Also, is the calculation/ code is correct for all the metrics?

Comment: As the result, the F1 is low because the recall is low.

Comment: RMSE is meaningless in classification problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is my code correct?**

Sorry, not entirely -

1. For the Precision, Recall, and f1 you should not be taking a mean of the curves such as `f1_train = np.mean(..`, Instead:
   Use your PR-AUC and ROC-AUC to define a threshold. Use that threshold to binarise the *y_pred_* *, and then call [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) for printing final precision, recall and f1 scores. You will, then, see the effective f1 score and how might precision and recall be impacting it.
2. `RMSE`: Go for a cross entropy metric may be (after you have binarised your predictions), because it is a classifier you trained.

Comment: How to use your PR-AUC and ROC-AUC to define a threshold? Are all the metrics calculation incorrect, in other words, do I have to binarise the _y_pred_*_  for all the metrics or some metrics of those can take the _y_pred_*_?

Comment: All curves look fine. You can read about finding a good threshold here and the links provided therein - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123124/how-to-determine-the-optimal-threshold-for-a-classifier-and-generate-roc-curve